# Insert all xml nodes of type 1 into a variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following:

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement;

for (i=0; i<root.childNodes.length; i++) {              

if (root.childNodes[i].nodeType==1){ // FILTERING NODE TYPE
myvar = root.childNodes.length;
alert (myvar.length);
}
}
```

The length returns 7 - which reflects ALL node types (unfiltered).

What I want is: myvar should contain ONLY node elements of type 1

How can I do that?

Thanks,
L.

Comment: Sorry but your script script just returns the amount of all child elements of root.
What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat function to get int val to cpmpare

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement;

for (i=0; i<root.childNodes.length; i++) {              

  if (parseFloat(root.childNodes[i].nodeType)==1){ // FILTERING NODE TYPE
     myvar = root.childNodes.length;
     alert (myvar.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that really serves your purpose but it should work.

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
var children = root.childNodes;
for (i=0; i<children.length; i++)
  if (children[i].nodeType==1) // FILTERING for element NODE TYPE
    alert(children[i]).length);
```

Let me know what you really want to do so I can edit this answer to make it fit better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always return the length of the array, regardless of the node type that it contains. If you want to get the number of node types that are equals to 1, you can use the code below:

```
root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
var counter = 0;
for (i=0; i<root.childNodes.length; i++) {              
   if (root.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1){
      counter++;
   }
}
alert (counter);
```